# "das + (was, wo, wie)"-structure in the sentence

Tags: grammar

I was told that in German a "das + was..."-structure is very useful in leading subordinate clause in mid of a sentence. For instance,

> 1. Ich möchte wissen, was er dir gesagt hat.
>    => Ich möchte das, was er dir gesgat, wissen.
> 2. Ich habe ihn gefragt, wo er jetzt wohnt.
>    => Ich habe ihn das, wo er jetzt wohnt, gefragt.
> 3. Ich möchte ihn danach fragen, wie er das Buch bekommt.
>    => Ich möchte ihn nach das, wie er das Buch bekommt, fragen.

I wanna know if it is right to say in such way.

Comment: Ich dachte, das sei " .....nach dem, wie...".

Answer (score 1):

Your first try nearly is correct. Correct would be:

```
"Ich möchte das, was er dir gesagt hat, wissen."
```

You can't use this structure for questions with "wo, wie, wer...", just for questions with "was".